# What is the sequence of writing the 卍 kanji?

Tags: kanji

How it will look like writen in 草書 ?

Comment: https://jisho.org/search/%E5%8D%8D%20%23kanji

Answer (score 1):

To address the second question "How it will look like writen in 草書 ?", I found an article commenting on "Kanji that do not look like Kanji", where they show an image of the 草書 for 卍:

[image]

Click [here](http://blog.livedoor.jp/miyataatsushi-nihongo/archives/37209041.html) to read the full article in Japanese.